# Using XML namespace with XmlSlurper in Groovy - how to query path correctly?

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have the following sample xml:

```xml
<root>

<table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <name>African Coffee Table</name>
  <width>80</width>
  <length>120</length>
</table>

</root>
```

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(someXMLText)
def hNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace(
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/", 'h')
def fNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace(
                    "https://www.w3schools.com/furniture", 'h')
println slurper.root[hNs.table].tr.td //not giving any response
```

As there is two table tags having different tags. How to fetch `Apples` value under tag  using gpath using namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the XML document is incorrect. When you define a namespace like `xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"`, you create a prefix that has to be used explicitly. Otherwise, you cannot query the document using this prefix if it is not assigned to any node. You would need to assign it to at least a `table` tag to make any use of it.

```
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</h:table>
```

However, if you want to create a default namespace for each `table` node (and its children nodes), you need to skip the prefix and define a namespace without it.

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Spot the slight difference - in the second example, we defined namespace with `xmlns` attribute, not the `xmlns:h` one as in the previous case.

When you use default namespaces, you can use the `declareNamespace` method to define prefixes for the default namespaces. This allows you to use a selector like `h:table` that refers to a `table` tag in the namespace defined by `h` prefix in the declared namespaces map. Consider the following example:

```groovy
def source = '''<root>

<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <name>African Coffee Table</name>
  <width>80</width>
  <length>120</length>
</table>

</root>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source).declareNamespace([
    h: "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/", 
    f: "https://www.w3schools.com/furniture"
])

assert root."h:table".tr.td.first().text() == "Apples"
assert root."h:table".tr.td.last().text() == "Bananas"
assert root."f:table".width.toInteger() == 80
```

In this example, we use an XML document that defines two different default namespaces for `table` tags. With the `declareNamespace` method, we can define prefixes for those namespaces so we can use the prefix in the tag selector.

If, for some reason, you need to define namespace with the prefix at the `table` node level, you need to use this prefix at least at the top level.

```groovy
def source = '''<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</h:table>

<f:table xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <name>African Coffee Table</name>
  <width>80</width>
  <length>120</length>
</f:table>

</root>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source).declareNamespace([
    h: "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/",
    f: "https://www.w3schools.com/furniture"
])

assert root."h:table".tr.td.first().text() == "Apples"
assert root."h:table".tr.td.last().text() == "Bananas"
assert root."f:table".width.toInteger() == 80
```

Hope it helps.